# How install and configure mysql 5.6.16 in windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows

I downloaded the zip file for Mysql 5.6.16, but there is no .exe file in the folder. 
All the instructions online are saying install through .msi file.
How can i install and configure mysql 5.6.16 in windows 7  ??
Thanx in advance

Comment: http://www.premiumwebbloghosting.com/2012/04/how-to-install-mysql-on-windows-7.html

Comment: Doubleclick msi file. It's same as .exe.

Answer (score 5):

As described in [How to install MySQL on Windows 7?](http://coranguweb.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/how-to-install-mysql-on-windows-7/):

> The installer installs the following software in your computer
>   a.) MySQL Server
>   b.) MySQL Connectors
>   c.) MySQL Workbench and sample
>   models
>   d.) MySQL for Excel
>   e.) MySQL Notifier
>   f.) MySQL for Visual
>   Studio
>   g.) Sample Databases
>   h.) Documentation
>
> 1. Download the installer here : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/
> 2. There are two options available: (as on 31 Jan 2014 , the latest version is 5.6.16)
>
>    (i) mysql-installer-web-community-5.6.16.0.msi – 1.5MB
>
>    (ii) mysql-installer-community-5.6.16.0.msi – 250.8MB
> 3. I personally prefer the 2nd option. This helps me to keep the .msi file as backup in my computer. I can install MySQL whenever I need to
>      even if I am offline.
> 4. After downloading the 250 MB file, double click it to start the installation process. Now it is simple as installing any software on
>      windows 7.
> 5. Once you are done with the installation download the official document
>
>    Direct link for A4 size pdf –
>      http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-5.6-en.a4.pdf
> 6. Now click the “MySQL Notifier” in programs menu. The Notifier icon appears in the task bar (right bottom). Right click on the small red
>      icon and select “start” the server option.
> 7. Click the “MySQL Workbench” in the programs menu. Start creating databases/schemas/tables/SQL scripts.

Comment: I was following your instructions, have downloaded mysql-installer-community-5.6.16.0.msi – 250.8MB, using this trying to add MySQL Server 5.6.21 - x64 from Available products, as soon as I select, I get an [error] - and have copied the [details] - just wondering why I got stopped installing MySQL server, Thanks. [error](http://i.imgur.com/stsjD5r.png)                    [details](http://jsfiddle.net/ramas/mwpfzcqm/)

Answer (score 1):

You can install mysql server on windows, using mysql web community installer. The web community installer is 32 bit, but you can use it install mysql on both 32 bit and 64 bit windows machines.

For step by step guide for installing mysql on windows machine, check this page [How to install MySQL server on windows?](http://www.rathishkumar.in/2016/01/how-to-install-mysql-server-on-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

Install Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer) from this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)  , even if your are using 64 bit operating system. MySQL Installer is 32 bit, but will install both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries.

Simply follow the steps and make sure to select the dependency for Visual Studio. Installer will download everything for you.

Answer (score -1):

Please Download Xampp Windows installer & install it on Windows. Hope this would work for you - www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwSCUHIzMsk .

Thanks

vJ

Comment: NO...I have aleady downloaded Mysql 5.6.16 source Zip file. I wannt to use it