# Visual studio 2012 connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012

I have downloaded and installed the following:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.6.html

But i still only have the following options to choose from in `VS`:
[image: My vs selection]

As you can see i cannot choose a normal MySql.

Can anyone tell me what i am missing or have experianced this problem before?

I have also attempted to update `Visual Studio 2012` but still without luck

Comment: because there's 32bit odbc and 64odbc and they are NOT interchangeable.

Comment: @MarcB meaning what exactly?

Comment: 64bit apps will use the 64bit odbc system and 32bit odbc drivers will be invisible to them, and vice versa

Comment: You should try and download this http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ The whole 250MB installation is what you want. Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112657/how-install-and-configure-mysql-5-6-16-in-windows-7