# MySQL Installer error on mysql-installer-community-5.6.21.1.msi

Tags: mysql, installation

I was following the [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112657/how-install-and-configure-mysql-5-6-16-in-windows-7), have downloaded mysql-installer-community-5.6.16.0.msi – 250.8MB, using this trying to add MySQL Server 5.6.21 - x64 from Available products, as soon as I select, I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkijK.png) - and have copied the error [details](http://jsfiddle.net/ramas/mwpfzcqm/) - just wondering why I got stopped installing MySQL server, Thanks

System:

```
    Windows 7 64 bit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bit weird as it mentioned in [instructions](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,621378,621469#msg-621469), all have to do is to change the system time [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pithf.png), and it's installed successfully.