# MySQL Workbench is not opening

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My OS is windows 7 ultimate 64 bits. I have downloaded the MySQL workbench ZIP from [here](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/).

Dearchivating, launching MySQLWorkbench.exe and..nothing happens.

It is loading for a few seconds and then nothing.

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few investigation I have resolved this by installing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages. Then the workbench starts successfuly.

Comment: Here is the link for latest Microsoft Visual 2015 C++ Redistributable package: https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe

Answer (score 2):

Use the Microsoft Installer(.msi) instead of the .zip file. That should clear up your issue. I believe Windows 7 and up requires the installer to avoid issues for certain software suites.

Comment: Actually this was my first attempt, the result is the same.

Comment: The msi would have warned you if a prerquisite is missing as it has specific checks exactly for that (and the .net 3.5 framework).

Comment: I found this other answer about this that may help you on here already. Click the link and scroll down. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112657/how-install-and-configure-mysql-5-6-16-in-windows-7

Comment: The last version supports Windows zip is 6.3.8.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [nice MySQL installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/) that does all the checks for you, points you to the download location if something is missing and eases setup on Win to a really simple task. I strongly recommend that you make use of that great (and free) tool.